# How to perform GET request with XML SOAP parameters with the Axios NPM library?

Tags: soap, axios

Axios lets you run GET queries with queries and parameters. Is there a way to pass in XML SOAP parameters into the Axios request?

```
await Axios.get(url, {
  params: xmls, // Is it this?
  data: xmls, // Is it this?
  headers: { "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8" },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP API call use by `axios.post()` instead of `axios.get()`

POST the enctype attribute can be multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded, whereas for METHOD="GET", only application/x-www-form-urlencoded is allowed.

GET only send a ASCII, when passing them through the URL in ASCII  data with being sent as part of the URL can't send multiple line of TEXT as XML format. On the other hand, binary data, images and other files can all be submitted through METHOD="POST" in body.

So that is why POST is common in SOAP API call instead of GET.

```
const response = await axios.post(
    url,
    payload,
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }
);
```

I will demo an addition in [calculator SOAP service](https://schemasxmlsoap.azurewebsites.net/soap/envelope/) : [Calculator](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx)

> WSDL(Web Service Description Language) is describing the functionality of a
> SOAP based web service.

### full code

```
const axios = require("axios");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const getAdd = async (a, b) => {
    const url = 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx'
    const payload =`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
            <soap:Body> \
                <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
                    <intA>${a}</intA> \
                    <intB>${b}</intB> \
                </Add> \
            </soap:Body> \
        </soap:Envelope>`
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            url,
            payload,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

getAdd(100,200)
    .then(result => {
        // display response of whole XML
        console.log(result);

        // extract addition result from XML
        const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(result);
        console.log('100 + 200 = ' + dom.window.document.querySelector("AddResult").textContent); // 300

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

### Install library

```
npm install axios jsdom
```

### Run program

```
node add.js
```

### Result

```xml
$ node add.js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.
xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns="ht
tp://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>300</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:En
velope>
100 + 200 = 300
```

[image]

Reference
[GET vs. POST](https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests)

Comment: Is SOAP and GET not compatible? Could you please describe that?

Comment: Thanks Bench, but the question isn't whether POST is better than GET. I have a SOAP GET API that needs to be called. I'm trying to figure out how to call it

Comment: Can you show me GET example call with real world URL?

Comment: Thanks Bench, after reviewing, it looks right

Comment: Thanks for your voted me. I happy to hear about that.