# How to set SOAPMessageContext Variables in Postman

Tags: soap, postman, jax-ws

I am trying to use Postman to test an old outdated SOAP Service.  The service is expecting some identities to be placed in a Handler Chain to obtain from the request.  In the request it obtains the values in the following manner (with some exclusions):

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Resource
private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

public MyResponse methodEvent(...) {
   ...
   String var1 = (String) context.getMessageContext().get("VAR1");
   ...
}
```

My question is when trying to use Postman how can I set this value in the request.  It is not part of the normal headers or other standard entries.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible before SOAP API call.
You can using the response of output to assign result variable
It can use other call output

From three different inputs

#1 Pre-request Script

#2 Global variable

#3 From other request output - I think you looking for this solution.

Demo - I will show [`ADD` operation](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add) in [`Calculator`](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx) SOAP

SOAP service URL

```
http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
```

Using variables `input_a`, `input_b` for adding

### #1  Pre-request Script

value defined at `Pre-request Script`

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("input_a", 3);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("input_b", 4);
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>{{input_a}}</intA>
      <intB>{{input_b}}</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Result
[image]

### #2  Global variable

[image]

Result
[image]

### #3 From other request output - XML parsing and assign variable

You can using this output variable for other SOAP call's input

```
var xmlTree = xml2Json(responseBody);
var text = xmlTree["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["AddResponse"]["AddResult"];
console.log(text)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("output_result", Number(text));
console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("output_result"));
```

[image]

Print the parsing variable

[image]

Comment: This is all setting variables in the postman environment and into the body of the request.  The body is an additional parameter in the message context.  The message context is a higher level than the body, query parameters, or header parameters.  I need to set a variables directly in the message context which is sent to the service so the service can retrieve it.

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723615/how-to-perform-get-request-with-xml-soap-parameters-with-the-axios-npm-library/74725772#74725772) using external variable to call via axio
Can you see it? Looking for this?

Comment: @bcoveny, it can be possible to add variable information at `HTTP Header`